# Regex (.NET) to validate any real number in several formats

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, numbers

I am trying to validate any real number in different formats using one regex rule in .NET. The formats I mean are the following:

**Dots (thousands) and comma (decimal)**

```
123 ; 1.234.567 ; 12.345.678 ; 123.456.789 ; 1.234.567,89 ; 1.234,56789 ; 1,2 ; 0,123
```

**Commas (thousands) and dot (decimal)**

```
1,234,567 ; 12,345,678 ; 123,456,789 ; 1,234,567.89 ; 1,234.56789 ; 1.2 ; 0.123
```

**White space (thousands) and dot or comma (decimal)**

```
1 234 567 ; 12 345 678 ; 123 456 789 ; 1 234 567,89 ; 1 234 567.89 ; 1 234,56789 ; 1 234.56789
```

I know a bit more that the basics about regex, so I have done this. No success so far.

```
(^|\s)(-|\+|±|\+/-)?(?:(([1-9]{1,3})([,]\d{3})*|[0]?)([\.]\d+)?)|(?:(([1-9]{1,3})([\.]\d{3})*|[0]?)([,]\d+)?)|(?:(([1-9]{1,3})([\s]\d{3})*|[0]?)([\.|,]\d+)?)(\s|$)
```

Can any one help me or link me to the solution if it is out there?

Comment: Yes, I did with no success so far...

Comment: Ok. Do you need it to be regex ?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be regex

Comment: And you want one regex to rule them all?

Comment: That's right! Is that possible using patterns (?: ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this may not be the optimal regex:

```
^\d*$|^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{1,5})?)$|^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,5})?)$|^(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:[,.]\d{1,5})?)$
```

But it does the job. I'll look how to make a better one in a near future. Here's a <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG2vB7/1)</kbd>

---

If your input is not *that* dirty (ie: once you have a space as a thousand separator you don't get dot then comma, not like `1 032,354.12`) you can use this simple version:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:[., ]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{1,5})?$
```

Which means:

- `\d{1,3}` <= start with 1 to 3 digit;
- `(?:[., ]\d{3})*` <= thousand separator with 3 digit after repeated 0 to n times;
- `(?:[.,]\d{1,5})?` <= decimal separator with 1 to 5 digit after it, 0 or 1 time.

Comment: Hi again! I tested them and decided to take the first one (big one) because  it doesn't allow wrong numbers (they can happen). However, I found another restriction: the number can be in the middle of a phrase so I modified it to allow white spaces (\s) too. The problem comes when the number is at the end of a phrase ending in dot (.) or comma (,) or whatever. It doesn't detect the number anymore. Could you help again, please?

Comment: @NullPointers you should ask another question with the input you really have, I'll be glad to (try to) answer it!

Comment: OKOK! Thank you! @Thomas